# compare 2 parameters with 1 coloumn while passing parameters in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have to pass two parameters (month var-char(2),year var char(4)),but these two parameters pointing towards one coloumn 'Myear'(values will be like this '03/14') now after passing parameters then i should compare with the coloumn 'Myear' then have to get data.kindly please any one help me out..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Myear` is `varchar`, then try this:

```
SELECT Myear
FROM TableName
WHERE SUBSTRING(Myear,1,2)=@month
    AND SUBSTRING(Myear,4,2)=SUBSTRING(@year,3,2)
```

Suppose `@Myear=03/14` and given parameters are `@month=05` and `@year=2013`, then it will check

if `03=05` AND `14=13`.

The syntax of `SUBSTRING()`:

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Comment: thanks but i have written in where condition its not working executing successfully but when i pass parameters its not showing data sir....

Comment: Is `Myear` of type `varchar`?